# c++ switch statement: group cases and give particular instruction for each case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    const int a = 9;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 9:
        // since a is 9, this ("good") should be printed
        std::cout << " good " << std::endl;

    case 4:
        // since a is not 4, this ("bad") should not be printed
        std::cout << " bad " << std::endl;

        // for both a==9 or a==4, this should be printed
        {
            std::cout << " always print me " << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The result should then be:

```
good
always print me
```

However this is not working. It there a way to do that in C++? Thanks!

Comment: Just put your `always print me` message printing out of switch statement body.

Comment: Use `if` instead of `switch`? For complicated conditions you really can't use `switch`.

Comment: Also note that without a `break` your code will print *both* `"good"` and `"bad"`.

Comment: switch cases are just labels. think switch case as an easier goto label system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of doing what you ask for inside a `switch`-statement short of using `goto`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int a{ 9 };

    switch (a)
    {
    case 9:
        std::cout << "good\n";
        goto foo;

    case 4:
        std::cout << "bad\n";
        goto foo;

    foo:
        std::cout << "always print me\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: of course there is ... simply put the `std::cout << "always print me\n";` after the switch, then it will be printed always

Comment: @user463035818 "There is no way of doing what you ask for **inside** a switch-statement"

Comment: @user463035818: but also in the default case (i.e. e.g. a=23)